# Finding latitude values that bound spherical segments of a desired surface area

Tags: spherical-geometry

Let's say we have a perfect sphere with surface area equal to 1. In the following diagram (not to scale), I need to calculate the latitudes of parallels ***A*** through ***G*** (based on the following specifications), but I'm having no luck.

[image: Descriptive image]

***A*** is the north pole (90°N), and ***G*** is the equator (0°); I'm trying to solve for the latitudes of ***B***, ***C***, ***D***, ***E***, and ***F***.

- The spherical cap centered around ***A*** and bounded by ***B*** has surface area 0.015625 (1.5625% of the sphere)
- The spherical segment bounded by ***B*** and ***C*** has surface area 0.015625 (1.5625% of the sphere)
- The spherical segment bounded by ***C*** and ***D*** has surface area 0.03125 (3.125% of the sphere)
- The spherical segment bounded by ***D*** and ***E*** has surface area 0.0625 (6.25% of the sphere)
- The spherical segment bounded by ***E*** and ***F*** has surface area 0.125 (12.5% of the sphere)
- The spherical segment bounded by ***F*** and ***G*** has surface area 0.25 (25% of the sphere)

As such, the total surface area of the cap and all the segments is 0.5 (50% of the sphere). How can I calculate latitude values for ***B***, ***C***, ***D***, ***E***, and ***F*** which provide segments of these sizes?

*P.S.: If you don't know how to do this calculation, that's fine! That makes you just like me! Just refrain from commenting in that case please.*

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: [area of the spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap)

Comment: I'm not asking for a direct answer, and I don't have the height (h) or the cap's base radius (radius of B), so the Wikipedia article is out. Please ensure your suggestions are relevant.

Comment: @mapp3r You don't need the base radius, please read more carefully before complaining.

Comment: You can deduce the radius of the sphere using the condition $4 \pi r^2 = 1$.  Then you could proceed using calculus taking the double integral of an angle along the great circle starting at the pole and the second path of integration a $2 \pi$ rotation around the pole.  Setting equal to the surface areas you have provided, solving for the first angle I specified is the answer.

Comment: @Phillip Hamilton, the phrase "taking the double integral of an angle along the great circle starting at the pole and the second path of integration a 2π
 rotation around the pole" doesn't make English sense, and as such, I'm having difficulty understanding what you're referring to. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: Have you had any calculus?

Comment: Or is this just regular HS geometry?

Comment: Using formulas from the wikipedia link in @Jean-ClaudeArbaut's comment, the latitude of $B$ is $\sin^{-1}(31/32)$, so that article is definitely not out.

Answer (score 1):

The area $\Delta A$ of each spherical strip  bounded by two lines of latitude is proportional to the change $\Delta z= \Delta (\sin \lambda)$ that measures displacement in the vertical $z$ direction along the North-South axis of the **unit-radius** sphere. (Here $\lambda$ is the  latitude angle.)

Since you know the percentage values of $\Delta A$ you can solve for the changes in $\lambda$ as you travel down the sphere.

See also [spherical bread crust area formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885436/spherical-bread-slices-area)

Comment: I could possibly do so if I knew more about the proportionality of their relationship. What I'm reading is that delta A = k * delta Z, but without knowing what replaces k, I don't have enough information to do so.

Comment: Total area of sphere of radius $R$ is $A=4\pi R^2$ and then total $\Delta z= 2R$